# How do I select a div that is not a child of the parent div but is outside the parent div?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to select the div with the class `nav` to change the `display` property to `block` when the user hovers over the `hamburger` div.

I've scaffold the internet and saw that some have said that you can achieve this if you use the `:not(insert_container_name_here)` pseudo-class, however, it does not seem to be working.

**The one requirement is that I cannot use Javascript.**

Below is my attempt at solving this problem:

```css
.nav {
  display: none;
  padding: 15px;

  background: red;
}

.hamburger {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px; 
  text-align: left;
}

.hamburger:hover .hamburger:not(.hamburger) > .nav {
  display: block;
}

.hamburger > .toggle-btn {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="hamburger">
  <a href="#" class="toggle-btn"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
</div>

<div class="nav">
  <p>Display</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) `~` you will be able to target the `nav` even if you decide to add other elements between the two.

```
.hamburger:hover ~ .nav {
  display: block;
}
```

Sample snippet

```css
.nav {
  display: none;
  padding: 15px;
  background: red;
}
.hamburger {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px; 
  text-align: left;
}
.hamburger:hover ~ .nav {
  display: block;
}
.hamburger > .toggle-btn {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="hamburger">
  <a href="#" class="toggle-btn"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
</div>

<div class="nav">
  <p>Display</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `+` [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) like this:

```
.hamburger:hover + .nav {
  display: block;
}
```

See demo below:

```css
.nav {
  display: none;
  padding: 15px;
  background: red;
}
.hamburger {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}
.hamburger:hover + .nav {
  display: block;
}
.hamburger > .toggle-btn {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="hamburger">
  <a href="#" class="toggle-btn"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
</div>

<div class="nav">
  <p>Display</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, I just wrote likely the same answer ;)